# How to know if data is updated in database with spring data cassandra

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

With spring data JPA if i write query like this:

```
@Query("update User u set  u.firstName=?1 where u.id=?2")
Integer updateFirstName(String firstName,String id);
```

`updateFirstName` method return either 0 or 1 based on update. But in spring data cassandra with this query:

```
@Query("update User set  firstName=?0 where id=?1")
Integer updateFirstName(String firstName,String id);
```

I am getting `null` . Is there is any way i can get confirmation that update operation is completed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Calling arbitrary CQL using query methods is possible but you need to align the return type (e.g. `Row`). Also, an `UPDATE` command does not return any rows hence you won't receive any result.

The confirmation that your call was successful is the normal termination of the query method.

Comment: I have updated my query to this: `@Query("update User set  firstName=?0 where id=?1")
Row updateFirstName(String firstName,String id);`  but i am getting this execution: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity must not be null!`

Answer (score 1):

`@Query` is used in Spring Data to select the values from the DB.

You can use the `@Modifying` along with `@Query`, which will trigger at the annotated method an "update query" instead of a "select one".

So the final form of that would be:

```java
@Modifying
@Query("update User set firstName=?0 where id=?1")
Integer updateFirstName(String firstName,String id);
```

Comment: `@Modifying` annotation is not available in spring-data-cassandra